# how can i insert normilized json data to mongod

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a normilzed data that I want to insert just [users] field to mongodb. I define a user model in my data base and I use 'normalizr' API to normalized my json data. finally how can I do this?

```
{
"entities": {
"users": {
  "nm0000209": {
    "id": "nm0000209",
    "name": "Tim Robbins"
  },
  "nm0000151": {
    "id": "nm0000151",
    "name": "Morgan Freeman"
  },
  "nm0348409": {
    "id": "nm0348409",
    "name": "Bob Gunton"
  },
  "nm0001104": {
    "id": "nm0001104",
    "name": "Frank Darabont"
  },
  "nm0000008": {
    "id": "nm0000008",
    "name": "Marlon Brando"
  },
 ...
```

Comment: Can you please clarify, if you are trying to update a single field in the collection OR need a way to normalize using mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **inserMany()** feature of mongo.

```
db.collection.insertMany([ users ])
```

For more info [read](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) this link.